# Named calculation subquery issue

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, ssas

I'm facing a little issue with SSAS, I'm trying to add a column to my fact table «Fact_Ventes» from a dimension table.

This is my query :

```
Select dc.[CuNumber]
from [Warehouse].[dbo].[Dim_Clients] dc
inner join [Warehouse].[dbo].[FACT_Ventes] fv  on fv.SK_Clients = dc.SK_Clients
```

and this is the error I got:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Can any one help me on this?

Comment: If the column is on a dimension table why do you need to add it as a calculation in the fact table?, that doesn't really make much sense

Comment: I need this column to make a count distinct measure by CuNumber on my fact table

Comment: I have a hunch that this is not the full code. If not, please paste the full sql query.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174859.aspx  and I wanna share it, it seems that my query need to be between brackets and I change the inner join to where clause , it works just fine  :

(SELECT        Dim_Clients.CuNumber
FROM           Dim_Clients 
                  where Dim_Clients.SK_Clients = FACT_Ventes.SK_Clients)

Comment: turns out I was missing the explicit mention of the fact table name before the column name which strangely enough wasn't mentioned here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174859.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0):

The Expression for a Named Calculation should return a Scalar Value.  Yours would return a result set.

I would abandon the use of Named Calculations and Named Queries, and access all data via SQL views.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you're just trying to update your Fact_Ventes table with a value from another table.  A simple UPDATE FROM should do the trick:

```
UPDATE [Warehouse].[dbo].[FACT_Ventes]
   SET fv.CuNumber = dc.[CuNumber]
  FROM [Warehouse].[dbo].[FACT_Ventes] fv
INNER JOIN [Warehouse].[dbo].[Dim_Clients] dc ON fv.SK_Clients = dc.SK_Clients
```

This assumes you've already updated your Fact_Ventes schema to include the new column.